# I used codeigniter zip class and all files download 0kb

Tags: php

```
public function downloadzip($argID){
    $data=$this->Audit_started_model->getZipImagesOfSchool($argID);
    foreach($data as $r):
        $filedata=$r->file_name;
        $filename=base_url()."uploads/files/".$r->file_name;

        if(file_exists("uploads/files/".$filedata))
        {
            $this->zip->add_data($filedata,file_get_contents($filename)); 
        }
    endforeach; 
    $this->zip->download(date('d-M-Y'));
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't mix using braces  `{}` and the alternative syntax (`foreach:/endforeach`) in the same code block since it makes it much harder to read the code. It's common to use the alternative syntax in views (for looping out elements on the page etc) but in normal PHP code, it's more common to just use braces.

Comment: The posted code would generate an empty zip if the files doesn't exist. I would check if the filenames you pass are correct and that you're checking the correct folder. Try `file_exists(__DIR__ . '/uploads/files/' . $filedata)` (if the `uploads` folder is located in the same folder as this code)